# selenium xpath to select following-sibling

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr class="k-grouping-row" role="row">
<td aria-expanded="true" colspan="6">
<p class="k-reset">
<a class="k-icon k-i-collapse" tabindex="-1" href="#"></a>
<span class="consolidation-group" style="font-weight: bold;" data-key="aedfdb66-bb11-4350-9d25-21941820141b">jhmfgjf (2 Items)</span>
</p>
<a class="k-button unconsolidation-link" onclick="UnConsolidateGroup("aedfdb66-bb11-4350-9d25-21941820141b", "8780f45d-0e81-4f5c-b206-61b682b27d67")" title="Unconsolidate all matter entries in this group">
<span class="marginRight5 icon-unlink"></span>
Unconsolidate All
</a>
</td>
```

I would like to click on the span "Unconsolidate All" using `following-sibling` operator. I tried the following code:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'jhmfgjf')]/../following-sibling::class[@title='Unconsolidate all matter entries in this group']
```

But it does not work, the first part does work, it's just the `following-sibling` part that does not work.

Any help would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The element's name is `<a>`, not `<class>`.

You should do the following:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'jhmfgjf')]/../following-sibling::a[@title='Unconsolidate all matter entries in this group']
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it worked. I could not figure out what was wrong. I will make sure of the elements next time

Answer (score 0):

Unconsolidate All is not a span element. Its a "a" element.

You can use

```
//a[contains(text(),'Unconsolidate All')]
```

And if you specifically want to use following-sibling , you can use in this way

```
//span[contains(text(), 'jhmfgjf')]//following-sibling::a[@title='Unconsolidate all matter entries in this group']
```

For reference and learning about sibling, ancestors in xpath , you can see [click here](http://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html)